# Zone Aware Routing in Envoy Proxy

Tags: envoyproxy

I am confused in using Zone Aware Routing in Envoy Proxy. Envoy's documentation is quite confusing and I can't imagine what a configuration file to perform Zone Aware Routing would look like. Who can help me?

I've read envoy's documentation and it's quite confusing, it's hard for me to visualize what a specific configuration file would look like.